# In pandas, how to differentiate between two equal ranks based on the value of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ranking

I have a dataframe `df:`

| Index | A | B | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | 27 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 62 | 15 | 2.5 |
| 3 | 76 | 15 | 2.5 |
| 4 | 85 | 04 | 4.0 |

Where the `'Rank'` column was created by ranking `'B'` in descending order. with :

`df['Rank'] = df['B'].rank(ascending = False)`

In rows `2` and `3` the ranks assigned are the same. Whenever there are same ranks assigned to two different rows, I want to break the tie by using the value of column `'A'` in descending order so that the row containing the higher value of `'A'` gets a lower rank.

Desired output:

| Index | A | B | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | 27 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 62 | 15 | 3.0 |
| 3 | 76 | 15 | 2.0 |
| 4 | 85 | 04 | 4.0 |

Edit:
I want to first rank it by `'B'` first, and then only use `'A'` to decide between the same ranked elements, such that all the other ranks are still decided only by `'B'`.

Comment: As per the suggested duplicate, you could do: `df['Rank'] = df[['B','A']].apply(tuple,axis=1).rank(method='dense',ascending=False).astype(int)`

Comment: `df.groupby(['A','B']).ngroup().add(1)`

Comment: Note that the accepted answer in the dup link is not recommended.

Comment: In the above code, does it give precedence to ranking by `'B'` first and then only using `'A'` to decide between the same ranked elements. such that all the other ranks are still decided only by `'B'`. ?

Comment: I don't think using aggregation as tuples (like in the linked answer) is a good idea: it is **slow**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option using [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
order = df.sort_values(by=['B', 'A'], ascending=[False, False]).index

df.loc[order, 'Rank'] = np.arange(len(df))+1
```

A variant combined with [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
df['Rank'] = (df.sort_values(by=['B', 'A'], ascending=[False, False])['B']
                .rank(method='first', ascending=False)
             )
```

Output:

```
   Index   A   B  Rank
0      1  55  27     1
1      2  62  15     3
2      3  76  15     2
3      4  85   4     4
```

Comment: COuld you please check the edit once and confirm? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @AbhishekBanerjee both my approaches should use B to rank and break ties based on A.